# Rewrite .aspx Url to .asp Url [SEO issues]

Tags: asp.net, .net, url-rewriting

HI guys i am working on a project where i have a .aspx page (index.aspx)
for some SEO reasons. seo guys wants me to show index.aspx url as index.asp

even the links in the page should also say index.asp

i have written this rule but it says file not found because it actually does not find the actual .asp file.. so i just want to rewrite url path from aspx to asp

```
<rule name="RewriteASPX">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.asp" />
</rule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This very simple way and very use full. In this way we can rewrite N number of pages and there is no need extra server configuration. Only you have to use Application_BeginRequest event. Inside this event use Context.RewritePath method to set which URL will execute internally in code behind. Here is the code:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Get the current path
 string CurrentURL_Path = Request.Path;

 if (CurrentURL_Path.EndsWith("x"))
     CurrentURL_Path = CurrentURL_Path.Remove(CurrentURL_Path.Length - 1);
   {
     HttpContext MyContext = HttpContext.Current;
     MyContext.RewritePath("CurrentURL_Path");
  }
}
```

**Note :** I have not text this code.

Comment: i tried your code but it comes up as 404 Error not found.